# How to replace the rows in data

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

Hello I have a table with 5 columns. One of the column X is:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
```

How can I change the order of numbers in vector X, for example on the first place put 3s, on the second place put 1s and on the third place put 2s. The output should be in format like:

```
x <- c(3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
```

And replace not only the values in the column X but all other rows for each number of X

**To clarify the question:**

```
X(old version) -> X(new version)
     1                2
     2                3
     3                1
So, If X=1 make it X=2
    If X=2 make it X=3
    If X=3 make it X=1
```

And if for example we change X=1 to X=2 we should put all the rows for X=1 to X=2

I have two vectors:

```
 x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
 z <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,30)
```

The desired output:

```
x  z
1  30
2  10
2  10
2  10
2  10
2  10
2  10
3  20 
3  20
3  20
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  Please provide a sample of the complete data set and desired result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r/1296745#1296745

Comment: @RichardScriven It`s not a duplicate since I am asking not to change the order to ASC or DESC

Comment: @user45415631.  Your updated version shows exactly the same idea that was before, but the expected result is different. X=1, make it X=2, X=2, make it X=3, if X=3, make it X=1.  Using my code.  x
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3; x1
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 just does what you asked. 
Also,  z[order(x1)]
# [1] 30 10 10 10 10 10 10 20 20 20, however `x` in desired output is not clear.

Comment: @user45415631.  I just updated based on the `desired output`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

```
 x1 <-c(2,3,1)[x]
 x[order(x1)]
 # [1] 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

#### or

```
  x[order(chartr(old="123",new="231",x))]
  #[1] 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

#### Update

If you have many columns.

```
 x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
 z <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,30)
 set.seed(14)
 y <- matrix(sample(25,10*3,replace=TRUE),ncol=3)
 m1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,z,y))
 x1 <- c(2,3,1)[m1$x]
 x1
 # [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 1


 res <- cbind(x=c(2,3,1)[m1$x[order(x1)]],subset(m1[order(x1),], select=-x))
 res
 #   x  z V3 V4 V5
 #10 1 30 10 15  2
 #1  2 10  7 23  9
 #2  2 10 16  5 11
 #3  2 10 24 12 16
 #4  2 10 14 22 18
 #5  2 10 25 22 19
 #6  2 10 13 19 16
 #7  3 20 24  9 10
 #8  3 20 11 17 14
 #9  3 20 13 22 18
```

Comment: Thank you! Do all other rows in table change the order along with X?. For example, if we change 3 to 1, I need all the rows when x=3 also go to the place 1

Comment: In your results you have 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2. So we have a new order, and I need to change the numeration: 1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3

Comment: `user45415631`.  I am not sure I understand.  You wanted the result to be `3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2`, right?.  Please show an example and the expected result you wanted.   x <- x[order(x1)] should change the `x`.

Comment: `user45415631`.  I just updated the code.  Please check if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I need! But how can I do if I have table (data.frame) with column X and many other columns like Z ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds as though you want to define your own order for sorting something. Is that right? Two ways you could do that:

Option #1: Make another column in your data.frame and assign values in the order you'd like. If you wanted the threes to come first, the ones to come second and the twos to come third, you'd do this:

```
 Data$y <- rep(NA, nrow(Data)
 Data$y[Data$x == 3] <- 1
 Data$y[Data$x == 1] <- 2
 Data$y[Data$x == 2] <- 3
```

Then you can sort on y and your data.frame will have the order you want.

Option #2: If the numbers you list in x are levels in a factor, you could do this using plyr:

```
 library(plyr)
 Data$x <- revalue(Data$x, c("3" = "1", "1" = "2", "2" = "3"))
```

Personally, I think that the 2nd option would be rather confusing, but if you are using "1", "2", and "3" to refer to levels in a factor, that is one quick way to change things.

Comment: Thank you! If I change the order in column X, do all other rows in table change the order. For example, if we change 3 to 1, I need all the rows when x=3 also go to the place 1.

Comment: And what is Y in version I

Comment: Yes, if you sort one column in a data.frame, R will automatically sort all the others.

Comment: And "y" in version 1 is the new column in your data.frame that you can sort by. Once you create that new column y, you can sort like this: `Data <- Data[order(Data$y), ]`

Comment: Ok, thanks! In your version you just change the order of the rows. But I mean the following: the number 3 in X need to be changed to number 1, number 1 changed to number 2  and number 2 changed to number 3 along with all rows. The output: result= (1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3). Sorry if it was unclear at first time )